# A basic question regarding or operator in python

Tags: python, if-statement, logical-operators

I get confused why the message always pops up like 'Welcome xxx' no matter what a user types.

```
username = input('Please enter your username: ')

if username == 'admin' or 'Admin' or 'ADMIN':
    print(f'Welcome {username}')
```

Sorry I know it seems a silly question but hopefully it helps beginners like me understand or operator in python better.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `if` condition doesn't work as you think. The correct usage is: `if username == 'admin' or username=='Admin' or username=='ADMIN'`. In Python strings are falsible, therefore it interprets it seperately as `if 'Admin'` which equates to `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is going on here is treating Python like it's a spoken language.

What you intend with:

```
if username == 'admin' or 'Admin' or 'ADMIN':
    # stuff
```

Is to mean:

```
if <condition>:
```

The "condition" being if username is 'admin', 'Admin', or 'ADMIN'.

But that's not how python works. Python reads

```
if username == 'admin' or 'Admin' or 'ADMIN':
    # code
```

as

```
if <condition 1> or <condition 2> or <condition 3>: 
    # code
```

--

> Condition 1: `username == 'admin'` is FALSE.

--

> Condition 2: `'Admin'` is TRUE. This is because 'Admin' is a string literal object, which exists, and is non-zero, not null, and not empty, and therefore true.

This is like going

```
myString = "any string"

if myString:
    # code is executed because myString is not empty.
```

But instead you're doing

```
if 'my string': 
    # this code would run.
```

--

> Condition 3: `'ADMIN'` is TRUE, for the same reason Condition 2 is TRUE.

--

**What you have going on here is that the `if` condition is always true, no matter was is typed.** Because

```
if username == 'admin' or 'Admin' or 'ADMIN':
    # code
```

Evaluates to

```
if FALSE or TRUE or TRUE:
    # code
```

And, therefore, will always evaluate to true and print whatever is in the `username` variable, even if it's not 'admin'.

Answer (score 0):

You want to go for:

```
if username == 'admin' or username == 'Admin' or username =='ADMIN':
```

Comment: This is an okay solution for three checks, but a nicer solution would be `if username in ['admin', 'Admin', 'ADMIN']:` or even better `if lower(username) == 'admin':` depending on what values need to be checked for

Comment: You're totally right

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem too.